# Connection dropped by Kaleido websocket

Tags: web3js, web3.py, kaleido

Connecting to Kaleido with websockets and listening on contract events works fine, but after some time (even if constantly receiving events) the connection is dropped by Kaleido.

The problem appears on web3js (@beta-37 and 55) as well on web3py(@4.9.2). I am currently using this workaround to reconnect after a dropped connection for js, which helps, but doesn't solve the actual issue.

```js
instance.events.allEvents().on('data', event => {
      if (event.event == eventName) {
         console.log(event);
      }
    }).on('error', console.error);
```

Expected would be that events keep coming in over the open websocket connection. Actually, I receive a 'Connection dropped by remote peer' error with code 1006 after a random amount of time.

Comment: Do you still have a problem?